# asp.net gridview column link

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I created a gridview column that is a link to a file stored on the server. The column gets the full file path from another column in the gridview, that gets its data in turn from a database table. I created an `itemtemplate` column as shown below. The link only works if I right click it and select "save target as".

How do I get the link to download or open the file when someone clicks on the link, instead of having to right click and select "save target as" to download the file?

```
<a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'>Download</a>




asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader" HeaderText="Download File"> 

<ItemTemplate> 
<a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'>Download</a> 
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader"></HeaderStyle> 
</asp:TemplateField>
The GridView layout
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFiles" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FileID"    AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
<Columns>
```

Comment: I think the order of the markups is not right. btw, what kind (MIME type) of files are those?

Comment: I downloading PDF and DOC files

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader" HeaderText="Download File">

                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'>Download</a>                                         
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>